# as3 calling the root parent class from sub class 1120: Access of undefined property parent

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class

hi there i am trying to call a root class function (back)? from a sub class but i am getting an error, i have tried a few things without luck. please help! cheers

Main class

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import foo;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        public function Main(){         
            var foo:* = new foo();
            addChild(foo)
            foo.call();
        }

        public function back(){
            trace("back");
        }
    }
}
```

Sub foo class

```
package  {

    public class foo {

        public function foo() {         
            trace("foo int");
        }

        public function call(){
            trace("foo, Main call");
            (parent as Main).back();
        }
    }
}
```

**My work around..**

main class;

```
package { 

    import flash.display.*;
    import foo;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        private static var main: Main;
        private var Foo: foo;

        public function Main(){
            Foo = new foo();
            Foo.call();
        }

        public static function get back(): Main {
            trace("foo!");
            return main;
        }
    }
}
```

foo class:

```
package {

    public class foo {

        public function foo() {
            trace("foo int");
        }

        public function call(){
            trace("foo, Main call");
            Main.back;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _foo_ should be successor of the _Sprite_

Comment: so i need to change foo class to sprite? is there any way to do this without changing the above?

Comment: thanks i have found a work around cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help guys appreciated but unfortunately that didn't work for me.. i found a work around, here's what i did. this is exacting what i needed (i didn't have an option to change the document class structure needed to stay the same).

```
package { 

    import flash.display.*;
    import foo;

    public class Main extends MovieClip {

        private static var main: Main;
        private var Foo: foo;

        public function Main(){
            Foo = new foo();
            Foo.call();
        }

        public static function get back(): Main {
            trace("foo!");
            return main;
        }
    }
}
```

foo class;

```
package {

    public class foo {

        public function foo() {
            trace("foo int");
        }

        public function call(){
            trace("foo, Main call");
            Main.back;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent` is a property of the `DislpayObject` class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent

This means that you should first extend it and second (very **important**) - you must add the child to any display list in order to use parent (as the ref says: *parent -> Indicates the DisplayObjectContainer object that contains this display object*)

Comment: I, as well as fsbmain explained you, that your child MUST be a DisplayObject in order to have a parent property. Sprite, MovieClip, anything you like. And it will work :)